# How can i check and see if a game server is online and then display that on my website?

Tags: php, jquery

An example would be http://www.gametracker.com/, except i just want to check and see if the servers online and if it is then display 
Server : xxx.xxx.xx.xx = ONLINE(Green light) and when its offline display
Server : xxx.xxx.xx.xx = OFFLINE(Red Light).

Comment: you can use an IF statement, is that a SQL server?

Comment: I want to be able to do what gametracker is doing with online game servers.  I have a gameserver on garrys mod and i want to be able to ping the server and see if its online and if it is the website will show so. if not then it won't.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your game server have a port number ...

```
function checkserveronline($ip, $port) {
    $fp = fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 5);
    if(!$fp){
        return "offline";
    } else {
        return "online";
    }
}

echo "<img src='/images/" . checkserveronline($ip, 80) . ".png' />";
```

In this case, if an IP:80 (HTTP Port) is offline, it will return `offline.png`, otherwise `online.png`.

This is my own function, you should make your own modification.

```
$ip = gethostbyname($domainname); // use this in case you don't know the ip.
```

FYR: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Ill do more research on it.

Answer (score -1):

On Terminal(Mac)/Command Prompt(Windows), `curl http://stackoverflow.com` will do that